# Flutter: Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I try to run my first flutter app and its given me this problem:

```
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

You can check this picture for more information:

[image]

Comment: Can you put the complete logs so we can solve this problem for you?

Comment: as in how i din't understand

Comment: Run `flutter doctor -v`and post any logs from `flutter run --verbose`